# Set Label string format from database column - <%# Eval("ValueColumn"), Eval("NumberFormatColumn") %>

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, data-binding, formatting, eval

I would like to format a label using a format string returned when the grid view is bound to a stored procedure. I want to do something like this, but not this as it doesn't work:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ValueColumn"), Eval("NumberFormatColumn") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Thanks. Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.Format` with `Eval`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" 
           Text='<%# string.Format("{0}, {1}", Eval("ValueColumn"), 
               Eval("NumberFormatColumn")) %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Or

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Eval("ValueColumn") + ", " + Eval("NumberFormatColumn") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

### Updated:

To format a string based on given `format string`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# string.Format(Eval("NumberFormatColumn").ToString(), 
               Eval("ValueColumn")) %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but these return values such as "12.53, {0:N1}" rather than "12.5"